# how to add bearer token in header in grafana dashboard API

Tags: grafana

I am new in grafana. in my project are implementing ouath2 protocol and we are sending bearer token in each REST call from UI to server,so I need to implement login for grafana so that we can add bearer token in grafana API call as well, I have API for token I can invoke from UI, I am able to get the token.
but unable to understand how to implement the login for grafana API

just add bearer token in Grafana REST API call how to configure so that bearer token will be added for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.